# SymmetricDS - help for row filter with subselect and ROUTER_EXPRESSION

Tags: filter, symmetricds

I am new to symmetricds.

When inserting a new record into the PRT_ITEM table, I need to reference the PRT_SUPPLIER table for the supplier code. If the PORTAL_ENABLED field is marked as "Y," the new record should be included in the replication subselection. In all other instances, it should be skipped.

I had created a custom router in SYM_ROUTER with subselection as
ROUTER_TYPE - subselect
ROUTER_EXPRESSION - c.external_id in (select SUPPLIER_CODE from prt_supplier where SUPPLIER_CODE=:SUPPLIER_CODE and PORTAL_ENABLED='Y')

and custom trigger SYM_TRIGGER as
EXTERNAL_SELECT - select supplier_code from prt_supplier where supplier_code=$(curTriggerValue).$(curColumnPrefix)supplier_code and portal_enabled = 'Y'

But this not working. Any clue what I am missing here

## TABLE - PRT_ITEM
ITEM_ID       NAME          SUPPLIER_CODE

11000001    Yummy Gum           S001
11000002    Noodles             S001
11000003    Soft Drink          S002

## TABLE - PRT_SUPPLIER
SUPPLIER_CODE   SUPPLIER_NAME      PORTAL_ENABLED

S001          ABC Limited        Y
S002          XYZ Corporation    N
S003          STAR INTERNATIONAL     N

Please guide to fix this

Comment: Is the column `prt_supplier.SUPPLIER_CODE` used as external ID of in the table `sym_node`?